# How to make a random draw from a mgcv GAM model

Tags: prediction, biostatistics, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Hi there statistical wizards!

I have a (maybe) minor problem, where I would like to use the predicted fit (`fit`) and standard error (`se.fit`) from a GAM model to take a random draw. Ideally I would like to know how to convert this standard error to a standard deviation so as to use `rnorm(mean, sd)` on each fitted value.

To compute the standard deviation from the standard error we need an N value, but I'm not sure how to compute this.

So far my code looks like this:

```
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)


eReefs.chl = c(0.24596960, 0.15762042, 0.10942775, 0.12170488, 0.08990742, 0.07395359, 0.08712383, 0.08182129, 0.08367566)
SON = c(-1.7, -1.1,  0.2, -0.2,  0.4,  2.4, -0.7, -0.7,  0.7)
years = 2010:2018

dat = data.frame(cbind(eReefs.chl, SON, years))

gamfit = mgcv::gam(eReefs.chl~s(SON, bs = "cs", k=4), data = dat)
mgcv::gam.check(gamfit)
plot(gamfit, residuals = T, pch=19, cex=1, xlab = "SON Nino3.4", ylab = "Median Chlorophyll Concentration", 
     all.terms = T, shade=T, shift = coef(gamfit)[1])

newdat = data.frame(SON = c(0.3,  0.8, -0.2,  0.1,  0.7, -1.0, -0.4,  2.3, -1.4, -1.3, -0.6, -0.3,  1.2,  0.3,  0.7, -0.3,
                            0.7, -1.4, -0.4,  1.0, -1.7, -1.1,  0.2, -0.2,  0.4,  2.4, -0.7, -0.7, 0.7), years = 1990:2018)

pred = predict(gamfit, newdata = newdat, se.fit = T)

# Now I want to draw from a particular year to run stochastic simulations, 
# so I want to create  a standard deviation from the SE, but I don't know N

#stddev = pred$se.fit*n
#rnorm(1, pred$fit[1], stdvev[1])
```

I would really appreciate some help on this, or an alternative approach. For context I am fitting about 1500 of these gam's so thats why I want to use the fit and standard error to draw from later after the model has been fit.

Comment: You understand that the standard errors only correspond to the expected value, not the prediction, right?

Answer (score 1):

That standard error is the uncertainty in the estimate for the expected/fitted value. For the variance of the posterior distribution, you want the estimated value of the variance (or scale parameter) for the model you fitted. You fitted something like

$$y_i = \beta_0 + f(x_{1i}) + \varepsilon_i$$

where $\varepsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, where the variance of the residuals (data) is estimated $\hat{\sigma}^2$. Another way of writing this is

$$Y \sim N(\hat{\mu}_i, \hat{\sigma}^2)$$
$$\hat{\mu}_i = \beta_0 + f(x_{1i})$$

Notice that $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is separate from the predicted value $\hat{\mu}_i$, and is an estimate of the variance of the data not the uncertainty in the predicted value. It is this $\hat{\sigma}^2$ that you want to get.

One way to do this for the Gaussian models you fitted requires three things:

- the expected value, which will be the value you pass to `mu`
- the estimated variance/scale parameter,
- observation weights, which we presume to be 1 here.

You already have `mu` as this is the fitted value for the new observation(s). The estimated variance/scale parameter can be extracted from the model as component `sig2` of the fitted model. (This may not exist in all GAMs fitted by mgcv, so we can try to extract it as

```
summary(model)[["dispersion"]]
```

but for these Gaussian GAMs, `model$sig2` will suffice, where `model` is your fitted GAM model.) Let's call this variance/scale parameter `sig2`.

In the case of weights, the standard deviation for use in `rnorm()` is

```
sqrt(sig2/wt)
```

where `wt` is the weight for that observation. As I presume you will want a weight of 1, then you can just use

```
sqrt(sig2)
```

This process extends to all of the models the `gam()` is capable of fitting — although the detail will be different.

You can get a function that given `mu`, `sig2` and `wt` will generate draws from the correct distribution for a GAM using the `fix.family.rd()` function in **mgcv**. You pass it the family function for the fitted model & extract the newly added `rd` component.

```
rdfun <- fix.family.rd(family(model))$rd
```

For Gaussian models this is:

```
> fix.family.rd(gaussian())$rd

function (mu, wt, scale) 
{
    rnorm(mu, mean = mu, sd = sqrt(scale/wt))
}
<bytecode: 0xd0e81b8>
<environment: 0x950aa40>
```

Which is where we see how this is implemented/computed.

As for the detail for other models, if you are unsure, consult the `rd` functions **mgcv** adds. For example, for the Poisson:

```
> fix.family.rd(poisson())$rd
function (mu, wt, scale) 
{
    rpois(length(mu), mu)
}
<bytecode: 0xd0e95a0>
<environment: 0xcd55138>
```

we see that we only need `mu`, the expected value to make draws from the posterior distribution, but for the negative binomial we need something extra, the $\theta$ parameter of the (particular parameterisation of the) negative binomial distribution

```
> fix.family.rd(nb())$rd
function (mu, wt, scale) 
{
    Theta <- exp(get(".Theta"))
    rnbinom(mu, size = Theta, mu = mu)
}
<environment: 0xe4f9c80>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was a really detailed and clearly written response :) I think I'm all set. You're a legend Gavin, my afternoon just got a lot easier

Comment: @SamMatthews Happy to help. My [*gratia* pkg](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/) has a `simulate()` method for GAMs, which encapsulates all of this, however it wouldn't be useful in this case if you don't want to save the models.

Comment: I'll definitely keep it in mind for future work. I've just already written my workflow so didn't want to mess around to much. Thanks again